# Misalignment in Profile and Ask a question pages

Tags: bug, design, badges, profile-page, plurals

Recently I've noticed the following misalignments

1. In empty about me section.

[image]

The gray filled part is shifted away from the boundary.

---

2. In sites, where the post tags are less, the green **Recommended** box hides the Badge name. Also the sizes of the inner boxes are not equal.

[image]

---

3. The green and red signs while reviewing a question before posting.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Also there is pluralization when there is only issue to be resolved.

Can these be fixed?

Comment: For that last one, I asked a question over half a year ago:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404118/question-couldnt-be-submitted-and-question-is-ready-to-publish-icons-arent

Comment: I have a feeling 1 and 3 are stylistic choices, certainly for 1. 3 just doesn't look right on a dark background.